Annotation using LabelImg and Python
I’m trying to annotate images using bounding boxes extracted from XML files and saved into a CSV. The first part of the code (XML to CSV conversion) works fine, but when I try to load the CSV and annotate images using OpenCV, I encounter two issues:

FileNotFoundError when loading the CSV for image annotation, even though the path seems correct.
`Some images don’t load, or annotations aren’t being saved in the output folder.

                for member in root.findall('object'):
                    value = (
                        root.find('filename').text,
                        int(root.find('size/width').text),
                        int(root.find('size/height').text),
                        member[0].text,
                        int(member[4][0].text),
                        int(member[4][1].text),
                        int(member[4][2].text),
                        int(member[4][3].text)
                    )
                    xml_list.append(value)
            except ET.ParseError as e:
                print(f"Error parsing {xml_file}: {e}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unexpected error with {xml_file}: {e}")
    
    if not xml_list:
        print("No XML data found.")
        return None
    
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    try:
        xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
        print(f"DataFrame created successfully with {len(xml_df)} rows.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating DataFrame: {e}")
        return None
    
    return xml_df

    if xml_df is not None:
        try:
            output_path = 'C:/Users/connie_france/Downloads/pictures/annotations.csv'
            xml_df.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
            print(f'Successfully converted XML to CSV at {output_path}.')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error writing CSV file: {e}")
    else:
        print("Conversion failed.")

Load the CSV file containing annotations
    if image is None:
        print(f"Image {row['filename']} not found.")
        continue
    
    # Get bounding box coordinates
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = row['xmin'], row['ymin'], row['xmax'], row['ymax']
    
    # Draw bounding box on the image (color: green, thickness: 2)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
    # Optionally add the class label on the image
    label = row['class']
    cv2.putText(image, label, (xmin, ymin - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 3.0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    # Save the annotated image to the output directory
    output_image_path = os.path.join(output_path, row['filename'])
    cv2.imwrite(output_image_path, image)

    print(f"Annotated image saved: {output_image_path}")


Please format the indentation probably.
